# Django-REST-Framework REST API within django app

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm wondering if there is a way to access REST API within the Django app.

I created a REST API using the Django rest framework. In the same project, I'm having another app in which I want to fetch data using my own rest API.

Comment: What do you mean by `access REST API within the Django app`? You can use the framework by importing it (`import rest_framework `) in your Django project, provided you've set it up correctly

Comment: I have a Django project in which I created two apps.
One for rest API and another for the web app. I want to fetch rest API data from ane to another app.

Comment: Sure, you can use the request module and make the request just like if it was an external API. But do you really need that? Why not get the data from the models directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to fetch that data on the client side you need to use and make an http request in [javascript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa/).
- If you want to fetch that data on the server side you already have the data, no need to fetch from the api, if you **really** need to do that there is the [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) module.